# Select new columns based on group order

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I went through many questions on this site but wasn’t able to find solution.
I’ve got a table:

```
Date    GroupID CHANNEL
24/02/2015  1   A
26/02/2015  1   B
27/02/2015  1   C
21/03/2015  2   D
20/02/2015  3   E
25/02/2015  3   D
28/02/2015  4   C
04/03/2015  5   B
05/03/2015  5   E
10/03/2015  5   D
11/03/2015  5   A
14/03/2015  5   C
23/03/2015  5   F
28/03/2015  6   E
```

Channel are limited to ‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D’,’E’,’F’.  There are quite a lot of rows in it with different GROUPIDs.

I need to get this table:

```
Date    GroupID Channel isFirst isLast  Channelsingroup Daysbeforelast
24/02/2015  1       A   TRUE    FALSE   3                   3
26/02/2015  1       B   FALSE   FALSE   3                   1
27/02/2015  1       C   FALSE   TRUE    3                   0
21/03/2015  2       D   TRUE    TRUE    1                   0
20/02/2015  3       E   TRUE    FALSE   2                   5
25/02/2015  3       D   FALSE   FALSE   2                   0
28/02/2015  4       C   TRUE    TRUE    1                   0
04/03/2015  5       B   TRUE    FALSE   6                   19
05/03/2015  5       E   FALSE   FALSE   6                   18
10/03/2015  5       D   FALSE   FALSE   6                   13
11/03/2015  5       A   FALSE   FALSE   6                   12
14/03/2015  5       C   FALSE   FALSE   6                   9
23/03/2015  5       F   FALSE   FALSE   6                   0
28/03/2015  6       E   TRUE    TRUE    1                   0
```

`IsFirst = TRUE` when the Channel is the first in the group of rows with the same ID sorted by Time; otherwise FALSE.

`IsLast = TRUE` when the Channel is the last in the group of rows with the same GroupID sorted by Time; otherwise FALSE.

`Channelsingroup` - number of rows in the same group (with the same GroupID)

`Daysbeforelast` - datediff in days between latest row in the group and the current one.

I have no access to create or update table, only to select.

I hope the above data make sense, any questions please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: Show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Hi Zohar, thanks.
I'm quite new to SQL, I've ordered and grouped my query. The problem is that after reading quite a lot (including on this site) i don't know how to add new columns with values based on sub-groups...

Comment: `29/02/2015` would cause an error. It should be `28/02/2015`.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it.

Comment: @user912830823, what is the version of Sql Server?

Comment: Ups, did it manually, fixed now. Thanks again! Can you have a look at clause frame question in the comment to your solution please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to use windowed aggregate functions:

```
select 
    *, 
    case when date = MIN(date) over (partition by groupid order by groupid) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end isFirst,
    case when date = MAX(date) over (partition by groupid order by groupid) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end isLast,
    count(*) over (partition by groupid order by groupid) Channelsingroup,
    datediff(day,date,MAX(date) over (partition by groupid order by groupid)) Daysbeforelast
from your_table
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c156e/1)

Comment: Hi @jpw, thank a lot! It works perfectly well in the sql fiddle example. 
When i tried to implement it in amazon redshift i got this error:
'Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;'

and when i tried to do it this way: 'partition by groupid order by groupid RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW' 
i got error:  'RANGE clause of window functions not yet implemented'.

Looks like they only support ROWS in frame clause. 

Do you know how to write frame clause based on ROW to make sure your solution works well please?

Comment: @user912830823 I have no experience with Redshift but you could try this `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` at least it works it mssql.

Comment: @user912830823 I think that should work, it looks correct according to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

Comment: thanks a lot! It works in the redshift as well. i'd never do it myself because i'm quite new to SQL and never heard about window functions. Now looks like i've got to figure out how this feature works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the `isFirst` and `isLast` column and `COUNT(*) OVER()` for the `ChannelsInGroup`. Additionally, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to compute for the `DaysBeforeLast`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cf74/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY [Date]),
        CC = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID)
    FROM TestData
)
SELECT
    c.[Date],
    c.GroupID,
    c.Channel,
    isFirst         = CASE WHEN c.RN = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END,
    isLast          = CASE WHEN c.RN = c.CC THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END,
    ChannelsInGroup = c.CC,
    DaysBeforeLast  = DATEDIFF(DAY, c.[Date], x.LastDate)
FROM Cte c
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
    FROM Cte
    WHERE 
        RN = CC
        AND GroupID = c.GroupID
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
)x(LastDate)
```

**Result**

```
|       Date | GroupID | Channel | isFirst | isLast | ChannelsInGroup | DaysBeforeLast |
|------------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------------|----------------|
| 2015-02-24 |       1 |       A |    TRUE |  FALSE |               3 |              3 |
| 2015-02-26 |       1 |       B |   FALSE |  FALSE |               3 |              1 |
| 2015-02-27 |       1 |       C |   FALSE |   TRUE |               3 |              0 |
| 2015-03-21 |       2 |       D |    TRUE |   TRUE |               1 |              0 |
| 2015-02-20 |       3 |       E |    TRUE |  FALSE |               2 |              5 |
| 2015-02-25 |       3 |       D |   FALSE |   TRUE |               2 |              0 |
| 2015-02-28 |       4 |       C |    TRUE |   TRUE |               1 |              0 |
| 2015-03-04 |       5 |       B |    TRUE |  FALSE |               6 |             19 |
| 2015-03-05 |       5 |       E |   FALSE |  FALSE |               6 |             18 |
| 2015-03-10 |       5 |       D |   FALSE |  FALSE |               6 |             13 |
| 2015-03-11 |       5 |       A |   FALSE |  FALSE |               6 |             12 |
| 2015-03-14 |       5 |       C |   FALSE |  FALSE |               6 |              9 |
| 2015-03-23 |       5 |       F |   FALSE |   TRUE |               6 |              0 |
| 2015-03-28 |       6 |       E |    TRUE |   TRUE |               1 |              0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select   DATE_1 ,GroupID,CHANNEL
         , case (select top 1 test.CHANNEL 
                 from test 
                 where test.GroupID = outer1.GroupID
                    order by test.CHANNEL) when outer1.CHANNEL then 'true' else 'false' end as isFirst 
        , case (select top 1 test.CHANNEL 
                 from test 
                 where test.GroupID = outer1.GroupID 
                    order by test.CHANNEL desc) when CHANNEL then 'true' else 'false' end as isLast
        , (select count(*)
           from test 
             where test.GroupID = outer1.GroupID) Channelsingroup 
        , (select DATEDIFF(DAY,outer1.DATE_1,MAX(test.DATE_1))
           from test 
           where test.GroupID = outer1.GroupID)

from     test outer1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte 
 as 
 (select Date,GroupID ,Channel,row_number() over (partition by groupid order         

 by groupid) as first
 from table1)
 select Date,GroupID, Channel, case when first=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as 
 isFirst,
 case when isfirst=b.Channelsingroup then 'true' else 'false' end as isLast
 b.Channelsingroup, datediff(dd,getdate(),Daysbeforelast) as Daysbeforelast
 from cte a
 inner join (select count(*) as Channelsingroup ,max(date) as Daysbeforelast 
 from table1 group by groupid) as  b 
 on a.groupid=b,groupid
```